# Topology Munkres Section 13 Problem 1

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am  starting to study topology with the book "Topology" by Munkres and I have a question regarding my approach to the first problem. The  problem says that given a topological space $X$, let $A$ be a subset of  $X$. Assume that for all $x \in A$ there is an  open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U \subset A$. Show that $A$ is open in $X$.

My solution: Since $U$ is open, then by definition for all $u \in U$ there exists a basis element $B$ such that $u \in B \subset U$. So, take any $x \in A$, and, by assumption, there exists open $U$ such that $x \in U $ but by our argument from above, there exists a basis element $B$ such that $x \in B \subset U \subset A$. Thus $A$ is open.

Is this right?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why not just say $A$ is the union of open sets $U_x$ so $A$ is open?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that solution and I think is simpler. But this was the first thing that came to my mind and just wanted to see if there is anything wrong with this. Maybe I am misunderstanding something and I want to see if there is a misconception here

Comment: Yes.  The other solution is simpler, as you acknowledge, but your solution is a correct proof.

Comment: Thank you very much!!